# SQLITE : inline views or nested subqueries?

Tags: sqlite, subquery

I'm trying to write a query on two simple tables. Tables are simple, the query is not :)

Anyway...
Here is the database scheme :
[image]

and here is an overview of table content :

[image]

I'm trying to write a query that would list all assets in corresponding table, only if the are marked as "wanted" (meaning the boolean field asset_owned =0) and that are referenced for another owner as "owned".

This is what I have so far and it works :

```
SELECT
    user.user_pseudo AS REQUESTER,
    asset.asset_sku AS SKU,
    asset.asset_name AS ASSET_NAME
FROM
    asset
INNER JOIN user ON asset.id_user = user.id
WHERE
    asset.asset_owned = 0
AND 
    asset.asset_sku IN (SELECT asset.asset_sku FROM asset   WHERE asset.asset_owned = 1)
```

But, in the same query (if possible) I would like to get the owner name as well.

The first result of such a query on those table would be :

me,003,Test003,you.

I've tried inline SELECT and nested subqueries like :

```
SELECT
user.user_pseudo as ASKER,
asset.asset_sku as SKU,
asset.asset_name as NAME,
subquery1.user.user_pseudo as OWNER
FROM
asset
INNER JOIN user ON asset.id_user = user.id,
(SELECT user.user_pseudo.asset_asset_sku FROM asset INNER JOIN user ON asset.id_user = user.id WHERE asset.asset_owned = 1) subquery1
WHERE
asset.asset_owned = 0 AND
subquery1.asset.asset_sku IN (SELECT asset.asset_sku FROM asset INNER JOIN user ON asset.id_user = user.id WHERE asset.asset_owned=1)
```

but of course that does not work.

Thanks for any direction you could point me to.

happy new year

Mathias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was fun for me (I'm learning SQL, so this is good practice!) - I appreciate the very clear question.

Hopefully this works for you - I used two sub-queries (one each for 'owner' and 'requester') and then joined those on SKU and name. It works in SQLite with the small sample data shown above.

```
SELECT requester, subq1.SKU, subq1.name, owner
FROM 
   (SELECT pseudo AS requester, SKU, name
    FROM asset, user
    WHERE owned = 0
    AND user.id = id_user) subq1,
   (SELECT pseudo AS owner, SKU, name
    FROM asset, user
    WHERE owned = 1
    AND asset.id_user = user.id) subq2
WHERE subq1.SKU = subq2.SKU
AND subq1.name = subq2.name;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and I learned how to use sub queries thanks to you.

Thanks a lot and happy new year Stidgeon.